# Can trim of a string be done inplace with C++20 ranges?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

Inspired by cute cppreference [example](https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp/ranges/drop_while_view&oldid=127184) of trim with C++20 I have written the following code(I have changed the return type to `void` and arg to `std::string&` since my "problem"(I am inventing problems to learn C++20) does not exist in original code that uses `std::string_view` arg and returns `std::string`).

```
void trim(std::string&  in)
{
    auto view
        = std::views::all(in)
        | std::views::drop_while(isspace)
        | std::views::reverse
        | std::views::drop_while(isspace)
        | std::views::reverse;
        std::string result{view.begin(), view.end()};
        in = std::move(result);
}
```

Issue here is that this is not inplace, meaning that new string is created.
I can write uglier code that does this inplace and I know that traditionally C++ algorithms have no idea that containers exist, but I wonder if C++20 has some tricks that enable me to do the trim in elegant way, but also inplace.

Here is my ugly inplace trim also(not sure if it works ok, but idea is that it does the trimming inplace):

```
void trim2(std::string& s) {
    // ugly and error prone, but inplace
    const auto it1 = std::ranges::find_if_not(s, isspace);
    const auto it2 = std::ranges::find_if_not(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), isspace);
    const size_t shift = (it1==s.end()) ? 0: std::distance(s.begin(), it1);
    const size_t result_size = s.size() - shift - ((it2==s.rend()) ? 0 : std::distance(s.rbegin(), it2));
    std::shift_left(s.begin(), s.end(), shift);
    s.resize(result_size);
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/hxrs5Kh1E)

edit: originally this question claimed `in.assign` would be UB, but T.C. corrected me. But based on my understanding of C++23 draft assign would still cause the temporary string to be created.

Comment: Working this out in my head: a straight-forward, in-place trim consists of: 1) a `find_if`, 2) an assignment, 3) a while loop with an if-conditioned assignment and 4) an erase(). A fairly basic, straightforward, simple implementation. Ranges are not a solution for every problem. The straightforward, simple approach, is done in exactly one iteration over the whole string. The absolute minimum that logic dictates is possible for something like this. How many times does the above go over, and over, and over, the range?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik probably twice(once for determining the view, and once for copy), since range views are maximally lazy. But I did not profile/debug this code, just a guess.

Comment: Where does cppreference say that for std::string?

Comment: @T.C. my mistake, I clicked wrong link, it is for std::vector::assign

Comment: @T.C. ah wait... assign is safe, but slow... I just read the draft of C++23, they do make copies... Equivalent to:return assign(basic_string(first, last, get_allocator()));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```cpp
void trim(std::string& s) {
    auto not_space = [](unsigned char c){ return !std::isspace(c); };

    // erase the the spaces at the back first
    // so we don't have to do extra work
    s.erase(
        std::ranges::find_if(s | std::views::reverse, not_space).base(),
        s.end());

    // erase the spaces at the front
    s.erase(
        s.begin(),
        std::ranges::find_if(s, not_space));
}
```

Comment: very nice, you do shift left and resize equivalent with smart ordering of erase.

Comment: btw is there a reason why erase in C++20 does not have range overload? too obscure usecase to care about it, or compile time worry(since string would need to know about ranges), or...?

Comment: `std::erase` and `std::erase_if` exist

Comment: @Yamahari but they would delete all spaces.

Comment: Can this method be used to remove special characters as well? (of choice?), also is this thread safe?

Comment: @Mecanik yes, lambda controls what is erased. thread safety depends on rest of the code not this function.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Understood, I am just looking to replace my current function with something better + be able to catch exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

`assign` with arbitrary iterators needs to create a temporary (because mutating the string can affect the iterator's result in arbitrary ways, and because a throwing iterator operation must leave the original string unmodified), but every major implementation does the right thing when given the string's own iterators.

So we can just unwrap the two level of `reverse_iterator`-ness:

```
auto view
    = in
    | std::views::drop_while(isspace)
    | std::views::reverse
    | std::views::drop_while(isspace)
    | std::views::reverse;

in.assign(view.begin().base().base(), view.end().base().base());
```

(I would have gone for Barry's answer myself though.)

Also, there's rarely any need to explicitly use `views::all`; the adaptors do it automatically.

Comment: This is actually amazing. I will never use this since it is too obscure, but the fact this trick works is amazing.

Comment: @康桓瑋 `views::common` does nothing here - `reverse_view` is already common. The point of the `base()` calls is not to make the view common, it's to take advantage of implementation optimizations by unwrapping the iterators.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible:

```
void trim(std::string& s) {
  auto view = s
      | std::views::drop_while(isspace)
      | std::views::reverse
      | std::views::drop_while(isspace)
      | std::views::reverse;
  auto [in, out] = std::ranges::copy(view, s.begin());
  s.erase(out, s.end());
}
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/x8rbTr49z).

Comment: are you sure this is fine?
Copies all elements in the range [first, last) starting from first and proceeding to last - 1. The behavior is undefined if result is within the range [first, last). In this case, ranges::copy_backward may be used instead.

Comment: I am mostly concerned about the fact that std::ranges::copy does not allow overlapping src and destination. I think if string is not trimmed at front your first it of source and first it of result are same